# Why is this A321 spoilers question closed as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, exact-duplicates

- [Do the different spoilers on an A321 extend by different amounts?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/89107/14897)

closed as dupe to

- [Why is there a difference in the max spoilers extension between the A320 and A321 in a roll?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/84089/14897)

One is asking **do,** the other is asking **why,** and the answers are different.

After sending it to the reopen queue, a comment was left saying:

> The answer for "do they do X" is certainly provided when the answer to "why do they do X" confirms that X happens as introduction to explaining why. I see no value in reopening, particularly since the OP found the duplicate thread to be useful.

1. This is not how dupes work on SE, even if OP pressed yes on the banner ([example](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/90218/can-anyone-open-an-exit-door-or-do-they-require-activation-by-the-crew#comment244311_90218))
2. **It wouldn't have been closable if it wasn't answered** (btw I answered the older one **after** the newer)

### Update

The [review](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/61187) (completed 4 hrs ago as of this update) was **3x** reopen vs **3x** leave closed (counting my review-initiating vote), i.e. it's not clear-cut.

RE aforementioned "This is not how dupes work"; my reference is the FAQ on the main meta re one answer addressing a similar question, not one unanswered uncited question addressing another. But given the tie and answers here, there's nothing else for me to do.

Answer (score 3):

I see the logic for closing it as "duplicate".

The other question asking "Why X?" implies that X is possible and happens.
And this is not challenged in the answer, confirming the hypothesis.

So asking "Do X happen?" is automatically answered by the other question, where it is also explained why.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is not about this specific question *or* even the original one, but rather about the op's assertion that the duplicate closure reason *only* applies to questions, and if one question is not a (exact or exact-ish) question it should not be closed as duplicate. In other words, it is their assertion that when two completely different questions are asked, they should never be closed as duplicates, even when one quality answer answers both questions.

In my opinion, which is backed by multiple other users, that is simply not correct. I looked through the main meta sight and it has been stated, actually repeatedly, that when there is a quality answer written as an answer to a question, and it is not down-voted (hence, quality), if that answer answers a different question, then the second question can and should be closed as a duplicate. Especially when/if the answer was chosen as accepted.

Yes, there are "rules" in Stack Exchange, but seeing as this is *by design* a community curated site, the rules are interpreted not by the few moderators, but by all of the community as a whole. In this particular community (e.g. [aviation.se] ) there have been many, indeed very many closed as dupes where the questions are not dupes, but the answers to one answer another.

Answer (score 1):

"Why X?" implies "Do X?" to some extent. Two such questions are often duplicates. But perhaps not always. Suppose the questions were asked in the reverse order.

The best answer to "Do spoilers extend by different amounts?" would include the exact amounts by which each spoiler extends, and possibly more description of their end-use.
The best answer to "Why?" would describe how it's better than having the same extension throughout.

An end-user question on system behavior and a design question on the reasons for it may coexist. For a simple yes/now, the former would be redundant however.